Openlayers Icon draggable on whole image not only anchor
I'm using a transparent marker with a cross on the center to add new features (trees) on a map. The marker should be draggable on the border, so that the user can position the cross exactly on top of the object, without hiding the cross with their finger (on mobile devices). After moving the marker a modal windows opens to fill in attributes for the new feature and save them to a database.
My code roughly does what I intend, but the marker is only draggable and visible when the pointer is over or close to its anchor point. When the pointer moves away, the marker disappears.
 var source = new ol.source.Vector({
      wrapX: false
  });

  var temp = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source
  });

 var mCross = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
    src: './images/mapmarker.png',
    scale: 0.6
    }),
 });


    // Longtouch interaction using ol-ext from http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/
var touchi = new ol.interaction.LongTouch({
  pixelTolerance: 1,

  // Handle longtouch > create a new feature
  handleLongTouchEvent: function(e) {
    var f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate));
    f.setStyle(mCross);
    temp.getSource().addFeature(f);
    
    var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
          features: new ol.Collection([f]),
          style: [mCross]
    });
  
    dragInteraction.on('modifyend',function(){
    var latlng = ol.proj.transform(this.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        document.getElementById("lat").value = latlng[1];
        document.getElementById("lng").value = latlng[0];
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); //opens modal form and save data
    },f);

    temp.getSource().clear();

    map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
  } 
});

map.addInteraction(touchi);

// Listen to longtouch event on the map
map.on(['longtouch'], function(e) {
  console.log(e);
})


Have you tried the hitDetection option as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-icon.html ?

Yes, I tried already to add 'hitDetection: temp' to  'new ol.interaction.Modify', but I don't see any difference. ('m stll using Openlayers 4.6.5).

A Translate interaction might be better (or even a custom interaction https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/custom-interactions.html)

I've tried to implement the custom-interactions, but i did not get them to work. I'll try again.

Translate interaction works https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/yLdMWYb?editors=1010&layout=left
